# Swapping Control and Windows (super) keys not working in Unity

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

If I open the Keyboard app, than go to layouts and click options, under Alt/Win key behavior, there is an option to swap the control and windows key. This seems to work when using classic gnome but fails when using ubuntu unity.

Comment: You are experiencing [bug #729007](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/729007). You can subscribe to the bug report to be notified of any progress.

Comment: This question should be and has been filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Bug report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/729007)